# Converting multiple btc private keys in standard text format to WIP

Tags: private-key, import, base58

Ok, going crazy! I have a file that lists my old private keys (2011) (not original wallet.dat, just keys txt file).  I need to convert each of these keys (not one at a time) into either a WIP key (base58) format or inserted into a new-wallet.  The only solutions I have seen are to convert one at a time.  I need a script to convert the raw private keys in the file with an output of the WIP keys, allowing me to import all at one time into a wallet ...

any suggestions ?  much thanks!  sky

Comment: also adding the original privkey is 64 chars rather than 32